# Calendar with reminders - application recommendation

Tags: windows, product-rec, calendar

Can anyone recommend a lightweight calendar application that will popup reminders?

I am looking for similar capabilities of the Outlook calendar (reapeating events, variable reminder times, daily/weekly/monthly views), minus the bloat...

**Edit:**

Ideally this would be an offline app.

Comment: Google calendar sems to be the most recommended... If you use it with google gears will it meet your 'offline' requirement?

Comment: Google Calendar with Google Gears isn't lightweight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nthing Google Calendar, however I would pair it with [Gminder](http://reflectivecode.com/gminder). This will allow you to get reminders for your events, even if you're offline.

Answer (score 5):

Well if you don't mind using a web browser, I cannot recommend Google Calenders more. It has all that you need.

If you use Chrome then you can set it up as an "Application" within chrome.

http://www.google.com/calendar

**EDIT:** As the question has been altered to say "Offline ideal" I would mention that Google Gears can be used to make it usable offline.

Comment: Plus, there are tons of ways to sync your Google Calendar with your local application.  Check out Mozilla Sunbird or Lightning if you use Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

[UK's Kalender](http://8ung.at/ukrebs/) is very nice, lightweight and feature rich.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom, Google Calendar is awesome, and getting even better with the new Labs functions. Next Appointment is currently my favourite.

It supports offline to a point where you can see your appointments whilst offline, but can only edit when online.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows Vista then you have Windows Calendar. It's decent and you get reminders even if you forget to start it so it's reliable in that way. I don't know if it has all the features you ask for though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a cellphone?

In my opinion cellphones are the best event reminders, as most of us own one and carry them everywhere.

Most cellphones can be synchronized with known calendar applications, including online ones, like Google Calendar. In fact, you don't even have to use a computer-based calendar for administering your events.

Besides, a cellphone is as offline as a device can be, you can use it wherever you go, with or without a working connection.

Comment: Untill stolen/lost...

Comment: There are applications that backup contents of cellphones. I'm using MyPhoneExplorer to sync my cellphone with Google Calendar, which also saves a backup of contents during synchronization. Your computer can be lost/stolen, too, what happens then if you have no backups?

Comment: @Oded: We can sync Nokia calendar with Outlook or Lotus Notes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about Sunbird as well. It has most of the same functionality of Outlook but it's pretty slim compared to Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has Daily/Weekly/Monthly views, but you might want to check out [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php).